# MySQL Is there such a thing as too much comment

Tags: mysql, comments

I'm trying to do a DROP CREATE stored procedure in MySQL.

The first block of code runs just fine.

```
DELIMITER //
-- IMPORTANT: Change to ecom_prod
USE ecom_dev;


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_getDetails`;
```

The second block gives an error in statement #2 near --DROP CREATE Procedure
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_getDetails`; at line 1

```
DELIMITER //
-- IMPORTANT: Change to ecom_prod
USE ecom_dev;

-- DROP CREATE Procedure
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_getDetails`;
```

The only difference is the addition of extra comments. I can't understand how the extra comment is causing this error.

**Any and all help is welcome**

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks are where you think they are?

Comment: the comment shouldn't be causing an error.. maybe its not recognizing it as a comment.. be sure there are spaces between your -- and the note. maybe tab it in and enter an extra line between the comment and DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the DELIMITER is changed to something other than semicolon, the new delimiter should be used in place of the semicolon.

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

-- IMPORTANT: Change to ecom_prod
USE ecom_dev$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_getDetails`$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm not sure how your code is working with the semicolons. I don't think the issue has  anything to do with the comments. But I haven't tested it. I always have a blank line preceding and following DELIMITER. And the only time I ever use `DELIMITER` is when I'm issuing a `CREATE <stored_program_type>`.

Comment: You nailed it.  The mysql command line client is a little bit inconsistent in its handling of `USE` statements (they are processed even if you hit enter, without a delimiter) (wrongly, imho) and by default, at least some SQL comments are wrongly (imho again) stripped out of statements by the client... so that could be why the code at least didn't throw an error... but yes, until you change the delimiter back to a semicolon, every statement (outside a stored program body) needs to be terminated with a delimiter.

Comment: I use the `-c` option on the `msyql` command line client (my rationale for that is to that comments are preserved in stored programs, without that option the comments get stripped out.) The behavior you observe may also be influenced by the `-c` option.